# Add Data for specific columns in Listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am trying to create an mini total commander for my practice.
At this moment , I want to add data from `C:\D:\E:\` to the columns like in a standard total commander.
Having at the moment 3 columns. *Name*, *Type*, *Date Modified*.

Comment: No idea what a total commander is... please explain better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are adding items to list view, subitems are mapped to columns (by index). So, if you have three columns in `ListView`, then you should provide `ListViewItem` with three sub items:

```
string path = @"D:\";
var items = from file in new DirectoryInfo(path).EnumerateFiles()
            select new ListViewItem(new string[] {
                    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name), // Name
                    Path.GetExtension(file.Name).Replace(".", ""), // Type
                    file.CreationTime.ToString()  // Date Modified               
                });

listView.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
```

Don't forget to set ListView view mode to `View.Details` - otherwise you will not see columns.